# Selecting sentences surrounding a keyword

Tags: python-2.7

I am a Python beginner. I tried to figure this out, but I failed. I need to find a keyword in a text file. If there is the keyword in any part of the whole text, then I need to select sentences surrounding the keyword, including the keyword. The number of sentences is arbitrary so it could be 5 or 10. There could be a blank line between sentences so I need to include the blank line as well.

For example:

Let keyword be: compensation

Let input text is:

"The costs incidental to our solicitation and obtaining of proxies, including the cost of reimbursing banks and brokers for forwarding proxy materials to their principals, will be borne by us. Proxies may be solicited, without extra compensation, by our officers and employees, both in person and by mail, telephone and other methods of communication."

The output I want for example: "The costs incidental... compensation... communication."

I tried to use this: p = re.compile( r'[^.]compensation[^.]+.') p.findall(text)

Using the above code, I can select only the sentence that contains the keyword. What I need is to select sentences surrounding the keyword. I need to control the number of sentences before and after the sentence containing the keyword. SO for example, if I want to select two sentences before the sentence containing the keyword, the sentence containing the keyword, and two sentences after the sentence containing the keyword, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is structured such: <sentence> <period> <sentence> <period>

Then you need to first select the full sentence which may start by your keyword, end by your keyword, start AND end by your keyword (although unlikely) for each match. Then you select the number of <sentence> <period> before and the same goes for after.

```
import re

s = open('text.txt', 'r').read()
p = re.compile(r'(([^\.]*\.){2}[^\.]*compensation[^\.]*\.([^\.]*\.){3})')
for i in p.findall(s):
  print("match='" + i[0] + "'")
```

Because we are using the group metacharacters '(' and ')', findall() will return a list of tuple of those, not what we want. So we add a group around the whole regex (which will necessarily be the first group as it is the outermost one).

EDIT: Another possibility is to use non-capturing groups (?:...). findall() will only return the full matches with those.

Allowing the number or sentences matched before (2) and after (3) to vary is left as an exercice (this should be easy to do using the string formatting facilities of Python).

## Output

> match=' Holy bacon. The costs incidental to our solicitation and
> obtaining of proxies, including the cost of reimbursing banks and
> brokers for forwarding proxy materials to their principals, will be
> borne by us. Proxies may be solicited, without extra compensation, by
> our officers and employees, both in person and by mail, telephone and
> other methods of communication. My. Oh My. God.'
>
> match=' C. D. My compensation is your compensation. E. F. G.'

## Text used

> Golly. Jeez. Holy bacon. The costs incidental to our solicitation and
> obtaining of proxies, including the cost of reimbursing banks and
> brokers for forwarding proxy materials to their principals, will be
> borne by us. Proxies may be solicited, without extra compensation, by
> our officers and employees, both in person and by mail, telephone and
> other methods of communication. My. Oh My. God. Feels. Good. To be.
> King of the Jungle.
>
> A. B. C. D. My compensation is your compensation. E. F. G. Hi. Ijjk.
> Lllme.